# Define live templates with the same abbreviation for different contexts

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

I'd like to define two live templates for `PHP` and `JavaScript` with the same abbreviation: `t`.

In `Live Templates` preferences I have set

```
$this->
```

for `PHP`, but I cannot set

```
this
```

in `JavaScript` because of error

```
Duplicate live templates in user group
```

Is it possible somehow to define those templates with the same keyword but for different contexts ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define live templates with the same prefix in different groups. If you specify different contexts for those, you'll get different behavior in those contexts.